# expected unqualified-id before QDir directory

Tags: c++, macos, qt, build

Building a Qt program on mac - It is functional in windows and Linux.

```
1  #include <QDir>
2  #include <QFileDialog>
3  ....
4  void afunction()
5  {
6    QDir directory;
7    if (! (directory.mkpath(mypath)) )
8    .......
9  }
10 void anotherfunction()  // likely irrelevant but showing why QFileDialog is included... no error here though
11 {
12   .....
13   filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, caption, filename, filter, 0, QFileDialog::ReadOnly);
14   ....
15 }
```

Error on line 6:

```
expected unqualified-id
  QDir directory
       ^
expected expresion
  if (! (directory.mkpath(mypath)) )
         ^
```

I clicked to "follow" the `QDir` and it took me to `qdir.h`

```
class Q_CORE_EXPORT QDir
...
```

seems it exists... I replaced "`directory`" with "`d`" and it passed this section of error... to give errors in `qfiledialog.h`... where a number of methods are using `directory` as a `QString`, while there is also a method `directory()`... the errors say "`expected ')'`"

I don't know how to deal with the errors shown on the actual qt files but I have learnt that when I see such errors, the problem is in the calling code.

Btw, trying

```
6    //QDir directory;
7    if (! (QDir::mkpath(mypath)) )
```

is even more wrong, `call to non-static member function without an object argument.` I wish there was a static version so I didn't have to create an object... But evidently I must do so, and there is a default constructor for QDir:

```
QDir(cost QString &path = QString());  inside `qdir.h`
```

Still, tried (just like the examples in qt documentation):

```
6    QDir myDirectory(mypath);
7    if (! (myDirectory.mkpath(mypath)) )
```

renaming "directory" leads to errors in `qfiledialog.h`, not renaming (using "directory" as a variable name), still gives me the same error in my code.

There must be some error somewhere ... I know the build options on the mac are more 'strict" than windows and even linux...

Could be possible that I am missing some includes ?

In the pro file, I have

```
QT += core \
      gui \ 
      svg
```

QT version on mac: 4.8.6 (on Linux built with 4.8.1)

I can't find what is causing my error, and I don't know what else to try ... The "similar questions" with a similar error that I have found either have code outside a function block, or use undefined class members... not the case here.

I don't know if the error is related to the mac compilers having a more strict setting, with the qt version, even with using qt itself (seems other people get this with c++ no qt), with my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all (your own) files you #include for correctness, i.e. balanced #ifdef ... #endif or missing semicolons at the end of class definitions etc. Start with the last #include.

Comment: Thank you for the response... It really was a #define problem... though not in the source files. please see my answer... But I will accept this since it is essentially what the issue was about.

Answer (score 0):

In the pro file, there is a `DEFINES` statement looking for the `svnversion`.

Unfortunately I don't have the svn directory... Which leads to it giving a response of `"Unversioned directory"`.

The `DEFINES` statement breaks down at the space, and tries to give a separate command... after only giving a warning about the fact that the constant `"Unversioned` is not defined properly

That virtually was equivalent to defining a constant

```
#DEFINE directory "
```

which was effectively breaking qt.